# Keras ModelCheckpoint overwrites previous best checkpoint when training resumed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback

I am using `ModelCheckpoint` callback from Keras:

```py
    checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath= model_filepath,
                                   verbose=1,
                                   save_best_only=True)
```

I cannot train my model in one step, so I have to save/load my model several times and resume the training to improve my model. However, when I load my model and resume the training, when the **first** epoch ends, since the **val_loss** changes from **inf** to some value (let's say **0.23**) the previous model will be **always** overwritten. But my **previous best val_loss** in the **previous** time that I was training my model was **0.19** (0.19 < 0.23 => the previous model is still the best => previous model should **not** be overwritten).

How can I tell Keras: Please consider the **previous best val_loss** in the **previous** time that I trained my model and stop this wrong behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not programmed for this purpose I would not consider it wrong.

I would suggest that you change the filepath parameter for of the callback whenever you resume your training, this way at least you do not lose the previous best.

Answer (score 1):

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LambdaCallback

work_dir = "drive/My Drive/Training Records/"
NUM_EPOCHS = 300
checkpointer_name  = "model_checkpoint.hdf5"
log_name = "log_"+checkpointer_name[:-5]+".log"
```

Step 1:

```
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = work_dir+checkpointer_name, 
                           monitor='val_loss', 
                           mode='auto', 
                           verbose = 0, 
                           save_best_only =False
                           )
checkpointer_best = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = work_dir+"best_"+checkpointer_name, 
                                monitor='val_loss', 
                                mode='auto',  
                                verbose = 1, 
                                save_best_only = True
                                )
```

Step 2:

```
def checkBestPerformance(epoch, logs):
    log_data = pd.read_csv(work_dir+log_name, sep=',', usecols=['val_loss', 'val_accuracy'], engine='python')
    min_val_loss = min(log_data.val_loss.values)
    max_val_acc = max(log_data.val_accuracy.values)

    current_val_acc = logs['val_accuracy']
    current_val_loss = logs['val_loss']

    save_filepath = work_dir+"best_"+checkpointer_name
    if current_val_loss < min_val_loss:
        model.save(filepath = save_filepath)
        print("\nval_loss decreased from", min_val_loss, "to", current_val_loss, ".")

    elif (current_val_loss==min_val_loss) and (current_val_acc>max_val_acc):
        model.save(filepath = save_filepath)
        print("\nval_accuracy increased from", max_val_acc, "to", current_val_acc, ".")

    else:
        print("\nPerformance did not improve from existing min_val_loss =", min_val_loss, ", max_val_acc =", max_val_acc, ".")
```

Step 3:

```
epochs_completed = 0
csv_logger = CSVLogger(work_dir+log_name, separator=',', append=True)

try:
    log_data = pd.read_csv(work_dir+log_name, sep=',', usecols=['epoch'], engine='python')
    epochs_completed = log_data.shape[0]

    if epochs_completed > 0:
        model = load_model(work_dir+checkpointer_name)
        list_callbacks = [checkpointer, LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=checkBestPerformance), csv_logger]
        print("epochs_completed =", epochs_completed)
except:
    list_callbacks = [checkpointer, checkpointer_best, csv_logger]
```

Step 4:

```
print("Previously completed epochs =", epochs_completed, "\n")

history = model.fit(final_train_imageset, final_train_label, 
                shuffle=True, 
                batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, 
                epochs = NUM_EPOCHS - epochs_completed, 
                validation_split = 0.1,
                callbacks=list_callbacks
                )
```